# Is accents package incompatible with unicode-math?

Tags: accents, unicode-math

I am getting an error using `accents` package with `unicode-math` in `xelatex`. The error is 'Missing number, treated as zero.'

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
$\hat{a}$   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load `accents` before `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\begin{document}

$\hat{a}\accentset{g}{a}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The `accents` package document asks for loading it after amsmath, so I loaded it after all math packages. The document may need an update.