# \XeLaTex with unicode-math and accents packages

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, accents

Using `\XeLaTex` with this code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}  
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
$ \mathring{A} $
\end{document}
```

gives me the error message

```
./mwe.tex:5: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.5 $ \mathring{A}
                   $
```

If I either comment out `\usepackage{unicode-math}` or `\usepackage{accents}` everything works fine. Is there an explanation? `PDFLaTeX` is working fine.

Comment: Did you switch the loading order?

Comment: I always delete the whole aux-files I get. PDFLaTeX ok -> deleting -> XeLaTeX failure. Is this the question?

Comment: That is not what I asked. Did you try loading accents first. Unicode-math like hyperref has to mess with a lot of things.

Comment: It can't "work" with pdflatex, as unicode-math doesn't work with it. Why do you want to use the accents package with xetex?

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370353/2388

Comment: @Ulrike: Missed this posting. I also forgot the amsmath-package.

Comment: `unicode-math` loads `amsmath` automatically. If you need any special options for `amsmath`, though, you’d want to load `amsmath` or `mathtools` with them before `unicode-math`.

Comment: @Davislor, I know, but \usepackage{accent} before \usepackage{unicode-math} without loading the ams math-package at first place gives the error. Maybe I skip using the accents-package.

Comment: Then why not `amsmath`, then `accents`, then `unicode-math`?

Comment: But, if you don’t need `accents`, by all means skip it. Never include packages you don’t actually use.